# Joomla k2 - Removing Item Title from Breadcrumbs

Tags: joomla, breadcrumbs, joomla-k2

How should I remove item titles from k2 breadcrumbs and only have category names displayed?

For example:

Home> Category1 > Category2 > Item Title

be turned to:

Home> Category1 > Category2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I share the answer that I found a few month ago:

In the path `/modules/mod_k2_tools/helper.php`, the line `$title = $row->title;` should be changed to `$title = "";`

And also, there are some good extensions to manipulate breadcrumbs.